# ImageMagick auto converting colored RGB image to grayscale?

Tags: python, imagemagick

How can i prevent imagemagick from converting my RGB channel images into a solid grayscale image? For some unknown buggy reason it's converting the final PSD image to a grayscale when it should remain as RGB.

It all breaks when i change the gradient of my background solid to be `'gradient:#f2f2f2-#f2f2f2'` instead of `'gradient:#FFA500-#f2f2f2'`.

What i want is this...

[image]

but i get this...

[image]

The process below is, I use one of the images as reference for size, in order to create a solid light gray background, i then stack all the images in sequential order starting with the solid background, then the shadow, then the chair and save it as a psd.

Below is all my code

Resources:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4awtl0ce8zm4lz7/shadow.png?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yupbaux5grfvo1j/foreground.png?dl=0

```py
import os
import subprocess
import sys

from PySide2 import QtGui, QtCore


CONVERT_EXE = '...ImageMagick-7.1.0-54-portable-Q16-x64/convert.exe'

def create_solid_background_im(filepath):
    solidOutput = os.path.splitext(filepath)[0] + '_solid.jpg'

    image_reader = QtGui.QImageReader(filepath)
    image_size = image_reader.size()

    cmd = [
        CONVERT_EXE,
        '-size',
        '{}x{}'.format(image_size.width(), image_size.height()),
        '-channel',
        'RGB',
        '-depth',
        '8',
        'gradient:#FFA500-#f2f2f2', # works as expected output RGB image
        # 'gradient:#f2f2f2-#f2f2f2', # makes final image grayscale
        solidOutput
    ]
    subprocess.Popen(cmd).wait()
    return solidOutput


def create_layered_image_im(filepath, files=[]):
    cmd = [
        CONVERT_EXE,
    ]

    for i, fp in enumerate(files):
        filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(fp))[0]
        args = ['(', fp, '-set', 'label', filename, '-channel', 'RGB', ')']
        cmd.extend(args)

        # photoshop bug need to duplicate first image added
        if i == 0:
            cmd.extend(args)

    cmd.extend([
        '-depth',
        '8',
        '-set',
        'colorspace',
        'RGB',
        '-channel',
        'RGB',
        filepath
    ])

    subprocess.Popen(cmd).wait()
    return filepath


if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_solid_background_im('foreground.png')
    create_layered_image_im('comp.psd', [
            'foreground_solid.jpg',
            'shadow.png',
            'foreground.png',
          ])
```

Comment: This appears to be more of a question of how to specify the arguments to `convert` (ImageMagick) than a programming question. Your question might be better received on a different SE, like [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Just before your output add the equivalent of command line -colorspace sRGB.